# How to launch pdf viewer from the terminal

Tags: terminal, pdf

I'm working using LaTeX, since I compile the document in the terminal, it would be much easier for me to open it in pdf viewer directly from the terminal.

I'm using OS X 10.8.2 in Polish, so I'm not sure of the English name of the viewer I'm using, but it's the default one, I guess it's `Preview` in English. But the command `preview <filename.pdf>` results in `-bash: preview: command not found`.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can just use `open <filename.pdf>` and your OS will use the default program to view PDFs. With `open -a Preview.app <filename.pdf>` your PDF is opened using Preview, even if your default PDF reader is something different.

Comment: that worked once for one file. for next file it didn't. on mojave.

Answer (score 4):

After discovering the "open" answer I wrote the following shell script, which I placed in `/usr/bin/acroread`:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/open $1
```

Don't forget to `chmod +x /usr/bin/acroread`. My LaTeX workflow is homogenized by this solution.

Comment: With SIP most users won't be able to `/usr/bin`, so `/usr/local/bin` might be the better place for this little script. It might also be useful to use `"$1"` to make it work with path/file names containing spaces.